# Change nav bar background to black once it hits container div

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Here is my website that I am working on.  http://www.acetronaut.com/

I want my navbar that is transparent, to have a background of black, once it scrolls to the container div and beyond.

I don't really know where to get started with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll event on `document` should work in your case and get the `outerHeight` of nav div and check whether position top of the document scroll is greater or equal then the value (height) of the nav div. If the condition is true `addClass("acetrnt-stickynav-color")` else `removeClass("acetrnt-stickynav-color")`

```js
var navbar = $(".acetrnt-stickynav-transparent");

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop(),
        header = navbar.outerHeight();
    
    if(position >= header) {
      navbar.addClass("acetrnt-stickynav-color");
    }
    else {
      navbar.removeClass("acetrnt-stickynav-color");
    }
});
```

```css
.acetrnt-stickynav-transparent {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    height: 5%;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: green;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 500px
}

.acetrnt-stickynav-color {
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="acetrnt-stickynav-transparent">Navbar</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Even better/cleaner using Css Classes ! :+1: nice @Adeel

Comment: @adeel this sounds right, but it is not working for me.  I have assigned a background black and font color of fefefe to a new class called .acetrnt-stickynav-color, and replaced that for sticky-color in your code, and it does not work.

Comment: @AceLong could you please update your question along with the code, btw I've added your class in my code snippet and it's still working, so it would be nice if you show us your code!

Comment: Hi there!  I got it to work.  http://www.acetronaut.com/

I used the following code.

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
        navbar = $('.acetrnt-stickynav-transparent');

    if (scrollPos > $('#container').offset().top - 50) {
      navbar.addClass('acetrnt-stickynav-color');
    } else {
      navbar.removeClass('acetrnt-stickynav-color');
    }
  });
});`

@Adeel

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it was the most help!  .addClass is definitely what I needed.

Comment: Hi, glad I could help you anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe :

1. listen on scroll event
2. when scroll is greater than a value (for example your container), put css rules to your nav bar `$(".acetrnt-stickynav-transparent").css('background','black');`
3. when scroll is less than a value, do the opposit

   ```
   $(function(){
       $(window).scroll(function(){
       var aTop = 50; //or $("#MycontainerId").heigth();
       if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
           alert('Scroll is over 50px.');
           // instead of alert you can colorize you nav bar
           $(".acetrnt-stickynav-transparent").css('background','black');
       } else {
           $(".acetrnt-stickynav-transparent").css('background','none');
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I tried and it's working so whenever I scroll, my code add a class "black" to my navigation bar, and whenever I go back to the top "When I'm not scrolling" my code remove the class "black" from the navigation bar. So first of all you need to style you "black" class in your stylesheet, then play with the jQuery.

```
nav.black{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 100%;
}

nav.black ul li a{
    color: #fff;
}
```

jQuery code on scroll add the class "black", else remove the class "black".

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $("nav").addClass("black");
    }
    else {
        $("nav").removeClass("black");
    }
});
```